# insert rows in google spreadsheets using R

Tags: r, google-sheets

I need to add new rows in a google spreadsheet document via R. I know how to read spreadsheets in R using Curl but I don't know if it's possible to insert new rows from R to google spreadsheets.

This is the code to read rows in a google spreadsheet

```
google_ss <- function(gid = NA, key = NA) 
{
  if (is.na(gid)) {stop("\nWorksheetnumber (gid) is missing\n")}
  if (is.na(key)) {stop("\nDocumentkey (key) is missing\n")}
  require(RCurl)
  url <- getURL(paste("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=", key,
                      "&single=true&gid=", gid, "&output=csv", sep = ""),
                cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
  read.csv(textConnection(url), header = T, sep = ",")
}
```

But I don't know if it's possible to return data from R to google spreadsheet

Comment: Please show us what code you have already written. Thanks.

Comment: Is http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/ useful?

Comment: Yeah! @Ben Bolker I think that this is the answer that I was searching

Comment: @calejero If you already found the answer, share it with the community! (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gs_add_row()` or `gs_edit_cells()` functions from the [googlesheets](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) package.  See the googlesheets [vignette](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jennybc/googlesheets/master/vignettes/basic-usage.html#edit-cells) for examples.